# DB2 relocate with multiple storeage paths

Tags: db2

I have this storage path setup

```
 /db2/inst/testtab/data/testtab/NODE0000/T00000/C000000.CAT
 /db2/inst/testtab/data/tab/SQLTAG.NAM
```

When I write the relocate.cfg file I know to include the STORAGE_PATH as

```
STORAGE_PATH=/db2/inst/oldtesttab/data/,/db2/inst/testtab/data/
```

however I then get the error that the SQLTAGF in tab cannot be found or opened.

If I wrote the /tab to the storage_path I get that the C00000.CAT cannot be found or opened.

When I write both in the STORAGE_PATH as

```
 STORAGE_PATH=/db2/inst/oldtesttab/data/,/db2/inst/testtab/data/
 STORAGE_PATH=/db2/inst/oldtesttab/data/tab/,/db2/inst/testtab/data/tab
```

it still says the C000000.CAT cannot be found or opened....

How can I relocate this DB?

Linux system without X Server no only command line. DB v10.5.9

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's the result of: `SELECT TYPE, PATH
FROM SYSIBMADM.DBPATHS`? What are the mv / cp commands you have run to move / copy your directories? What's your relocate config file contents?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to run OS mv command, move current path to new path, before run db2relocate.
Here is one of good article for your reference.
**[Db2] Simple test case shell script for db2relocatedb command**
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/1099185

```
- snip -  

2. Save below as repro.sh and run "chmod 777 repro.sh".  Then execute it.
-----
#!/bin/sh
# prepare objects for test
db2 drop db DEV
db2 create db DEV
db2 connect to DEV
db2 "create table t1 (c1 int)"
db2 "insert into t1 select rand()*1000 from syscat.columns fetch first 4000 rows only"
db2 "select count(*) from t1"
db2 list db directory
db2 terminate
db2stop
# mv database directory and run db2relocatedb with relocate.cfg
mv /home/db2inst1/db2inst1/NODE0000/DEV /home/db2inst1/db2inst1/NODE0000/PROD
db2relocatedb -f relocate.cfg

- snip -
```

It is suggested to review it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

so I found the answer,

I moved everthing before so that was not the case but I had to include a

```
 CONT_PATH=/db2/inst/oldtesttab/data/tab/,/db2/inst/testtab/data/tab/
```

to the relocate.cfg